# How to do Lombok compound or aggregate building

Tags: java, lombok

It seems like an obvious requirement, so I'm surprised that there aren't any accessible examples, but I have a class with a Lombok builder annotation on it, which contains a class that also has a Lombok builder on it, like so:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "priceList", "assetRate", "name", "id", "attributes", "description" })
public class T24Element {
    private T24PriceList priceList;
    private String assetRate;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    @Singular("attribute")
    private List<ReferenceDataItem> attributes;
    private String description;
}
```

The T24PriceList and ReferenceDataItem are as follows:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class T24PriceList {
    private PricedItem leaseTermPrice;
    private PricedItem assetFee;
    private PricedItem basePrice;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ReferenceDataItem.ReferenceDataItemBuilder.class)
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "description", "code", "endDate" })
public class ReferenceDataItem {

    private String description;

    private String code;

    /**
     * Rarely used - seems to be only for leasePeriod reference data
     */
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate endDate;

}
```

Finally, PricedItem is:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PricedItem {
    private String priceType;
    private String matCode;
    private String currencyMnemonic;
    private BigDecimal value;
}
```

The problem I am having is that no matter how I am using the builder I can never get the `@Builder` annotated classes inside the other classes build as anything other than `null`. So, for example, if I start with:

```java
    public static T24Element t24Element = T24Element.builder()
        .priceList(t24PriceList)
        .assetRate("GP")
        .attributes([shortCutKey, coreServiceType, size, sellerPid, leasePeriod, capacity,
                     renewAttribute, dimensions, sellerPid2])
        .id("903551")
        .name("Small Post Office Box")
        .description("Personal mail")
        .build()

    public static T24PriceList t24PriceList = T24PriceList.builder()
        .assetFee(assetFee)
        .basePrice(basePrice)
        .leaseTermPrice(leaseTermPrice)
        .build()

    public static PricedItem leaseTermPrice = PricedItem.builder()
        .priceType("ZPOB")
        .matCode("903551")
        .currencyMnemonic("AUD")
        .value(new BigDecimal("253.92"))
        .build()

    public static PricedItem assetFee = PricedItem.builder()
        .priceType("ZPBF")
        .matCode("903613")
        .currencyMnemonic("AUD")
        .value(new BigDecimal("25"))
        .build()

    public static PricedItem basePrice = PricedItem.builder()
        .priceType("ZPOB")
        .matCode("903551")
        .currencyMnemonic("AUD")
        .value(new BigDecimal("277"))
        .build()
```

the value of `t24PriceList` will be null. Even though `basePrice` on its own initialises correctly, when I try to use that value in:

```java
    public static T24PriceList t24PriceList = T24PriceList.builder()
        .assetFee(assetFee)
        .basePrice(basePrice)
        .leaseTermPrice(leaseTermPrice)
        .build()
```

it's always null. It looks like Lombok can't see the builders of the aggregated classes. What am I supposed to do here?

BTW: I realise that I'm using lots of annotations, but I have been trying different combinations such as `@Getter` and `@Setter` instead of `@Data` and so on to try to get this to work.

Comment: What makes you think `basePrice` will be initialized before `t24PriceList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static fields are not `final`, which means it is absolutely legal for them to be null during the class initialization. Your `basePrice` is effectively null when building `t24PriceList`.

If you set them `static final`, the compiler should give you a warning if you use a constant before its declaration. Or just try to move your `basePrice` declaration before `t24PriceList`.

Comment: thanks - I just moved my "basePrice declaration before t24PriceList" it wasn't getting initialised. Yep, rookie mistake.